# There are red lines on my screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu, gpu-driver, visual-artifacts

Ever since I got this Gigabyte GTX 750 Ti video card, it's had red lines all over the screen as is it was repeating exclamation points or semicolons. Even after I added the driver it seemed fixed until I rebooted. How do I get these off or check if I installed the software correctly?

[image: the little red lines, mostly on the top of the screen]

[image: another view of the same thing]

Comment: Which video card, which driver and add a screenshot =)

Comment: http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/86390 and a Gigabyte GTX 750 Ti video card, ill send a picture in a min, its on another computer

Comment: looks like printscreen doesnt show, one second

Comment: @Pilot6, this is for you I believe. :)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I installed the driver incorrectly, I found the following procedure to repair:

From the grub menu>advanced settings>recovery mode, then after a loading screen pick *root*.

```
cd /
```

to enter the main directory

```
sudo fsck -Af -M
```

to fix a disk error preventing me from editing files with a read-only error

```
mount -o remount /
```

to reload

```
rmdir -rf tmp
```

to delete the folder where it was trying to save but couldnt,
then go run the driver

```
cd home/(user name)/Downloads
```

to get into the directory

```
./(filename)
```

it should recreate the directory and install correctly, if not just do

```
cd /
```

and

```
mkdir tmp
```

Comment: +1 for answering  your own question 2 years later :) Don't forget to click on the grey mark beside your answer. This let's other people know the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Before you dive into the driver, you need to prove the hardware is good. First, take the card out and plug it back in to eliminate a seating problem. Make sure the power cable is disconnected from the PC and take ESD precautions. If that doesn't help, continue. From the manufacturer web site it appears to be a GV-N75TOC-2GI, for which there was a BIOS update released on June 4th 2015. You could get the latest firmware, if it's not at version fd0, and install it (you will need to do this natively in Windows (ie not under VM). You could also run a GPU test - I use GPUTest from http://www.geeks3d.com/gputest/. You could start off by running the test if you prefer.